# Social implications of using a prepaid card only instead of a bank card?

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account, debit-card, checking-account

Many times one is asked to give an account transaction list in pdf (what are they called??) Perhaps when buying a house or starting a new job. I'd like to use a prepaid card account that accepts wire payments, one that has an IBAN number, instead of a normal debit account, for my salary and all daily transactions. What are the social disadvantages of this preference? Is a bank account really not substitutable by prepaid cards? Financially there's no difference for me but how would it make my life harder when someone wants to see my account summary?

Comment: I'm not from the UK. What is the difference?

Comment: I'd question "many times".  One generally needs an account statement if you're applying for a home loan but that happens a few times in a life.  But I'm hard-pressed to imagine why a new employer would need to see a statement.  If you're really worried about being able to get a mortgage, a lot will depend on why you're avoiding the regular banking system.  If that's the only unusual thing about your finances, an underwriter might look a bit more closely at your file but that's about it.  If you do other unusual things, however, that might raise red flags.

Comment: Can your emplayer even pay into a prepaid card account?  Most expect to pay into a bank current account.

Comment: @SimonB Some employers in the United States do this if you don't give them a bank account number. They don't want to give you a paper check every payday.

Comment: You've asked for a card that can accept incoming transfers and has an account number. I have to ask how this is different from an ordinary bank account, and what your reasons for avoiding a more usual account are?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Pre-paid cards are notoriously difficult/terrible to deal with if you have to do anything outside of a simple transaction.

Checking the balance is a chore.

The website is usually an abomination.

Customer service is usually non-existent and the toll-free number is 100% automated with no way to speak to a person.

The bank which issued the card has a tendency to sell their assets numerous times, much like how debt gets sold.

I don't even want to imagine the process of getting your money in cash or getting it transferred to a real bank once you realize how atrocious the experience is.

I can't even begin to imagine the nightmare of losing your card which was issued by a bank which only exists virtually and is unwilling to talk to you.